# How to load attributes without nested object from associated models in sequelize nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations, associative

how to return a user object array without any nested object in the array elements?
one user has one role and one role belongs to many users(one to many releation between user and role)
I need to execute this query

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name,users.email,users.status,roles.role
FROM webuser users 
JOIN webuserrole roles ON roles .id= users.role_id;
```

this is sequlize function
let user =await webuser.findAll({

```
            attributes: [
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'status',
                 ],
            include : [{ model: webuserrole, attributes: ["role"]}]

        });
```

this is the result of the above function return user array object

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "jack",
        "last_name": "leach",
        "email": "jackleach@gmail.com",
        "status": true,
        "webuserrole": {
            "role": "admin"
        }
    },
    {
        "first_name": "ben",
        "last_name": "duck",
        "email": "benduck@gmail.com",
        "status": false,
        "webuserrole": {
            "role": "admin"
        }
    }
];
```

This is I expect the result

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "jack",
        "last_name": "leach",
        "email": "jackleach@gmail.com",
        "status": true,
        "role": "admin"
       
    },
    {
        "first_name": "ben",
        "last_name": "duck",
        "email": "benduck@gmail.com",
        "status": false,
        "role": "admin"
       
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            attributes: [
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'status',
                [Sequelize.literal('webuserrole.role'), 'role']
            ],
            include : [{ model: webuserrole, as: 'webuserrole', attributes: []}]

        });
```